# How to use 'if' to condition and ignore a word in a particular sentence?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

How can I construct a condition that if a phrase has the name "x", then "x" is ignored when the phrase is displayed?

**Example:**

```
if(item.contains("Text"))
{
    //Then ignore "Text" and display the remaining mill
}
```

Comment: You can just use the `substring()` method to get the `String` before and after the ignored text.

Comment: what is a "remaining mill"? examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use :

```
String item = "This is just a Text";
if (item.contains("Text")) {
    System.out.println(item.replace("Text", ""));
}
```

Comment: Why bother with `contains` first? Just do:

    `String item = "This is just a Text"; System.out.println(item.replace("Text", ""));`

If it doesn't contain the target, the same string is returned by `replace`.

Edit: How do you create a code block in a comment?

Comment: yes @jingx this is a good point, but maybe the OP need some actions not just the print the string, so he/she should to use if, right?

Answer (score 4):

here,
**replace()**   can be used.
 public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)

**Parameters:**

*oldChar* : old character

*newChar* : new character

```
public class ReplaceExample1{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String s1="stackoverflow is a very good website";  
        String replaceString=s1.replace('a','e');//replaces all occurrences of 'a' to 'e'  
        System.out.println(replaceString);  
    }
}
```

**O/P:**

```
steckoverflow is e very good website
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-)** method combined with a ternary operator

```
String val = "How can I construct a condition that if a phrase ";
String valFinal = val.indexOf("that") != -1 ? val.replace("that", "") : val;
System.out.println(valFinal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the best way, but off the top of my head:

```
    String x = "This is Text";
    String[] words;
    String newX = "";

    words = x.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(!words[i].equals("Text"))
                newX = newX + " " + words[i];
    }

    System.out.println(newX);
```